# How can I write text on a panel in c#?

Tags: c#, panel, windows-forms-designer

I want to click a button and than a specific text is written on a panel

I have tried "panel.items.add(Text1);" but it did not work

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextSchreiben("Text");
    }

    private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string TextSchreiben(string Text1)
    {
        panel1.items.add(Text1);
        return Text1;
    }
```

Comment: You either need to use custom painting (which I wouldn't generally recommend) or add a control (e.g. a label) with the given text.

Comment: @Jon Skeet You mean I just put a label onto the panel and address the label instead of the panel? So I would have to type "label1.items.add(Text1);" ?

Comment: No, you'd do something like `panel1.Items.Add(new Label { Text = Text1 });`. Note that C# is case-sensitive, hence `Items.Add` rather than `items.add`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool textSchreiben(string textStr, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
     Label textControl = new Label();
     textControl.Text = textStr;
     textControl.Location = new Point(x, y);
     textControl.ForeColor = Color.White;
     panel1.Controls.Add(textControl);

    return true;

    }
    catch { return false; }
}
```

usage would be

```
    bool created = textSchreiben("your text", 0 *x cords, 0 *y cords);
```

or make the function a void.

Answer (score 0):

Add a label control to the panel.  Set text value to empty string.  Then when the button is clicked, fill the text value of the label with your message.

You can also pre-fill the label with your message and toggle the visibility.